# issues when installing photoeditorSDK

Tags: html, photoeditorsdk

We have found some issues when installing photoeditorSDK in our website: [twin-meme.com](http://twin-meme.com).

We have followed these instructions:

https://docs.photoeditorsdk.com/guides/html5/v4-DesktopUI/introduction/getting_started

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- React Dependencies for the SDK UI -->
    <script src="js/vendor/react.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/react-dom.min.js"></script>
    <!-- PhotoEditor SDK-->
    <script src="js/PhotoEditorSDK.min.js"></script>
    <!-- PhotoEditor SDK UI -->
    <script src="js/PhotoEditorDesktopUI.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/PhotoEditorDesktopUI.min.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="editor" style="width: 100vw; height: 100vh;"></div>
    <script>
      window.onload = function () {
        var container = document.getElementById('editor')
        var editor = new PhotoEditorSDK.UI.DesktopUI({
          container: container,
          license: 'YOUR_LICENSE', // <-- Please replace this with your license. Please make sure this is in *string* format, not *object*.
          assets: {
            baseUrl: '/assets' // <-- This should be the absolute path to your `assets` directory
          }
        })
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Obviously, we updated the license ;)

Then, we have changed JS filenames at index.html which were different to the downloaded files.

```
<script src="js/PhotoEditorSDK.UI.DesktopUI.js"></script>
<link charset='utf-8' rel="stylesheet" href="css/PhotoEditorSDK.UI.DesktopUI.css" />
```

We found the following error message:

```
TypeError: t is undefined
PhotoEditorSDK.UI.DesktopUI.js:7:2237
```

After that, we added the default image in order to solve this:

```
var editor = new PhotoEditorSDK.UI.DesktopUI({
container: container,
license: 'MY_LICENSE', // <-- Please replace this with your license. Please make sure this is in *string* format, not *object*.
assets: {
baseUrl: '/assets' // <-- This should be the absolute path to your `assets` directory
},
editor: {
image: '/assets/test.png'
}
});
```

But then, we got another error message:

```
TypeError: e.addEventListener is not a function
PhotoEditorSDK.js:9:1859
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? each time We solve some error shows up another one. This is really frustating
 :(

Does anyone have any demo project working online? That would help us to get to know what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the version 4.1.4
https://github.com/imgly/pesdk-html5-build/tree/v4.1.4/js ?

It seems our docs are not correct. I will update them accordingly.

The error seems to result from the fact that the SDK itself (not the UI) is not properly loaded.

Try this please

```
 <head>
    <!-- React Dependencies for the SDK UI -->
    <script src="js/vendor/react.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/react-dom.min.js"></script>
    <!-- PhotoEditor SDK-->
    <script src="js/PhotoEditorSDK.js"></script>
    <!-- PhotoEditor SDK UI -->
    <script src="js/PhotoEditorSDK.UI.DesktopUI.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/PhotoEditorSDK.UI.DesktopUI.css" />
  </head>
```